# How to calculate sum of fibonacci series?

Tags: input, while-loop, printing, integer

Take an integer x as input from the console using input() function. Calculate Fibonacci series one number less than the given input x, and also calculate the sum of all alternate numbers (Even-numbered) in the resultant list. Print the result to the console as shown in the example.

Sample Input and Output 1:
k: 25
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
sum: 33

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The Fibonacci numbers are the numbers in the following integer sequence.
0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, ……..
In mathematical terms, the sequence Fn of Fibonacci numbers is defined by the recurrence relation

```
Fn = Fn-1 + Fn-2
```

by using recursion in python.

```
    # Function for nth Fibonacci number
    def Fibonacci(n):
        # Check if input is 0 then it will
        # print incorrect input
        if n < 0:
            print("Incorrect input")

        # Check if n is 0
        # then it will return 0
        elif n == 0:
            return 0

        # Check if n is 1,2
        # it will return 1
        elif n == 1 or n == 2:
            return 1

        else:
            return Fibonacci(n-1) + Fibonacci(n-2)

    # DFunction call
    print(Fibonacci(25))
```